# PHP pdo-mysql timeouts on 2000sec(too long!)

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo

In high traffic environment, some PHP sessions stay about 30 minutes and end up with `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] connection timed out` in PDO constructor.
According to New Relic's trace, the wait time is just 2000 seconds.
The long wait seems that PHP had reached out MySQL server but connection establishment would have stopped in half way.

I want to shorten the wait time to 30 seconds but I cannot find out any configuration where to set.
Any suggestion?

---

environment

- PHP7.0.16
- Amazon Aurora
- AWS Ubuntu Linux

what I have tested but not worked

- `set_time_limit(30)`
- `ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 30)`
- `new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'pass', [PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 30])`
  (This works only if the destination is unreachable)
- Any async library using `pcntl_signal()` as attempts to abort the PHP script.
  But the event never occurs while the main thread is stopping at `new PDO()`

MySQL variables contains `time`

```
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value             |
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time     | 0                 |
| connect_timeout                 | 10                |
| delayed_insert_timeout          | 300               |
| flush_time                      | 0                 |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout     | 1                 |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                |
| innodb_old_blocks_time          | 1000              |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF               |
| interactive_timeout             | 28800             |
| lock_wait_timeout               | 31536000          |
| long_query_time                 | 0.010000          |
| net_read_timeout                | 30                |
| net_write_timeout               | 60                |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout          | 31536000          |
| slave_net_timeout               | 3600              |
| slow_launch_time                | 2                 |
| timed_mutexes                   | OFF               |
| wait_timeout                    | 28800             |
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Have you looked into MySQL slow query log?

Comment: I have and I think it won't help.
The code is stopping at PDO constructor, no query would not have sent.

Comment: Sorry - I would have thought optimising the database queries would reduce how busy the database server is.  This would mean connections would be freed up faster.

Comment: Thank you. Optimizing should make a good impact.  
But that's not the point this time.

While the system handling 15G bps traffic, we observe HTTPd long remained processes(30min) due to TCP packet losses(I guess). So I'm looking for any solution to shorten their lives in a graceful way.